# How to send a header with laravel api response?

Tags: php, laravel, api

I need to set a header with my api response.

I tried like this

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return Blog::all()->header('X-Total-Count', Blog::all()->count());
}
```

How to send this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses), the following should work:

```
return response(Blog::all())
    ->header('X-Total-Count', Blog::all()->count());
```